# Partial View cannot access Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and trying a few things out, so I'd appreciate if someone can tell me where I am going wrong.  I converted this from VB where it worked, but now, in C# it doesn't.  Maybe my conversion is bad, but similar code is working in VB.

I pass the Model to the Index (which will later render several partials and I'll build a ViewModel to hold each different type of model).  Then, I try to pass the Model to the Partial, but the Partial cannot access the Model in the foreach loop.

Below if the code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult HospiceSummary(int? id)
    {
        IEnumerable<PatAdm> patadms = (from pa in db.PatAdms where pa.AdmNum == id select pa).ToList();
        return View(patadms);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PatAdm>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "View";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>.... Some other code up here</h2>

<h2>Hospice</h2>
<div class="container-fluid">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_PatientAdmissionSearch.cshtml", Model)
</div>
```

Partial:

```
    @model IEnumerable<PatAdm>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-header">
            Find a Patient
        </div>

    </div> @*col-xs-12*@
</div> @*row1*@

<div class="row">


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Admission", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" class="span2 search-query" id="query" name="query">
                <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Patient Name</th>
                <th>Acct #</th>
                <th>Admit Date</th>
                <th>Discharge Date</th>
                <th>DOB</th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "HospiceSummary", "Hospice", new {id = item.AdmNum}, new { @class = "label label-info"}) <br />
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.LName), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.FName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmNum)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AdmDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DischDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.DOB)</td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    }


</div> @*row2*@
```

Comment: What error exactly is it throwing?

Comment: The first thing I notice is there is no 'Model' in intellisense in the Partial View.  Then, when I run it, I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @L_7337 Most probably this - `IEnumerable<PatAdm> patadms = (from pa in db.PatAdms where pa.AdmNum == id select pa).ToList();
        return View(patadms);` is returning null. I don't know why but you better check with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Leron.  There was something wrong with the PatAdm when I converted the project from VB.  Once I was able to get this to populate correctly, it worked. 

Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model of Parent view is by default passed to the partial view, So you don't need to pass explicitly. Also make sure that the model on parent view has value.

Comment: Thanks @AshishCharan. I found the answer from another comment, but your answer was informative, so +1.

Comment: The model was returning null and I fixed this in the controller.